# How to do arithmetic without assignment?

Tags: arithmetic

I have known that I can use "advance...by..." to do arithmetic on number in TeX, but is there any way to do arithmetic without changing the value of number? For example, if I want to determine whether a number called X whose value is x satisfies x^2+x+1<0, and keep the former value of X for future use, what can I do?

Comment: If it's really simple stuff and only integers you can use: `\numexpr\myX*\myX+\myX+1\relax`. So in a test this becomes: `\ifnum\numexpr\myX*\myX+\myX+1\relax<0` (but there is no real value satisfying that inequation).

Answer (score 5):

You can e.g. use xfp:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand\myxvalue{15}

\begin{document}

\ifnum \fpeval{\myxvalue^2 + \myxvalue + 1} < 0 \relax 
        yes  
\else no: it is \fpeval{\myxvalue^2 + \myxvalue + 1} 
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: this does not sound robust because a priori `\fpeval` produces floating point numbers (as digit tokens with dot) which would immediately cause problems with `\ifnum`. (for example if computations needs more then 16 digits of precision) Hasn't LaTeX3 introduced `\numeval` or `\inteval` ? but maybe this is only a wrapper to `\numexpr` hence no `^` operator.

Comment: @jfbu yes you are right. One would have to use also the tests from l3fp.

Comment: Thinking again, I would expect your answer to be perfectly fine with integer only computations as long as final result fits in TeX bound (it appers, but I have not checked really, that `\fpeval` will not output `15.0` for example but `15`), but the problem is with `/` which is not rounded integer division hence a discrepancy with `\numexpr` based computations.

Comment: Out of sheer stubborness: try `\fpeval{\myxvalue^1000/\myxvalue^999}`.

Comment: `\xinttheiexpr \xintfloatexpr\myxvalue^1000/\myxvalue^999\relax\relax` is only about 2.5x slower (\*) as `\fpeval{\myxvalue^1000/\myxvalue^999}` and does output `15`. (\*) I must improve ;-)

Comment: @jfbu there are expandable fp to int function. But I can't add it now.

Comment: @jfbu hack: `\ifdim\fpeval{...}pt<0pt` (untested)

Comment: @Skillmon alternatively to `\ifdim` the etoolbox expandable tests `\ifdimcomp` et al. can serve as wrappers too as you do, until similar user interface gets added to `xfp` (maybe it is there already??)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\xinttheiexpr ...\relax` will be very happy to round `\fpeval` located inside `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

The `xfp` package is wrapper to access at user level the "Floating Point Unit" of LaTeX3. All its operations are expandable.

At the core level they use crucially the e-TeX addition to Knuth TeX of `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr`... which allow expandable computations with infix notations (and some sometimes surprising restrictions).

using directly `\numexpr/\dimexpr` might be all you need.

Maybe you need computations with integers bigger than `2^31` and you want `^`operator? and factorial with `!`? then you can use [bnumexpr](http://www.ctan.org/bnumexpr).

For even more complicated things like `add(x(x+1), x=1..100)` you can use [xintexpr](http://www.ctan.org/xint).

An earlier package allowing expandable computations inclusive of powers was `intcalc` but without infix notations, only macros. Also `bigintcalc` does it with integers exceeding the `2^31` bound (`intcalc` achieves expandable computations even if the TeX-engine is lacking e-TeX `\numexpr`; this is interesting theoretically but quite slower in practice. It does use `\numexpr` if the latter is available).

As mentioned above `xintexpr` has extended infix syntax (and is faster when computing with "big" numbers). `bnumexpr` is a more light-weight package, which hooks also into the core arithmetics provided by `xintcore`, but does not develop as extensive a syntax as  `xintexpr`.

Naturally at some point you will want to actually store the computations somewhere, via an `\edef` for example; so the computations are done expandably, without assignments, which is nice for `\ifnum`, for `\write` etc... (for embedding in some TikZ things, too), but at end of day you almost always have to do something unexpandable...

Then, things like `fp`, `pgfmath`, `pgfplots`, `apnum`, are math engine doing things non-expandably to start with (maybe I forget some, please complete). The `apnum` is arbitrary precision.

As per your original question, perhaps something in this style:

```
\xintdefvar X := whatever with big integers and fractions;
% 
\xintifboolexpr{X^2 + X + 1 < 0}{Yes branch}{No branch}
```

The first steps does the computations expandably and defines variable X. Then `\xintifboolexpr` is purely expandable and evaluates `X^2 + X + 1` with no assignments.

Of course as was observed by @Skillmon always the No branch is taken here... (there is no interface to complex numbers in `xintexpr` so far).

Comment: Even if there were an interface to complex numbers, it doesn’t make much sense to compare complex numbers with zero… ;-)

Comment: @GuM You aren't completely wrong ;-)... It does make sense, it would expand to yes branch if the complex number is real negative. What does not (with no extra considerations) make sens is to compare two general complex numbers via  `<`.

Comment: @GuM If I define the predicate `z<0` like I said it behaves correctly with addition, with multiplication by a real positive number, and even by multiplication of two such things if I have also defined similarly `z>0`. Hence it does make sense, despite the fact that we prefer that math undergraduate don't read these lines ;-)

Comment: Fair enough… :-)

Comment: @GuM the key thing is to avoid defining a `z>=0` as opposite of `z<0`. Because then this new predicate does **not** behave nicely with respect to addition, contrarily to `z<0`. Thus to some extent `z_1 < z_2` may be defined, and also  `z_1 > z_2` but it will not be true that either `z_1 = z_2`or `z_1 < z_2`or `z_2 < z_1`.